# simplesamlphp configuration as idp

Tags: php, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

```
SimpleSAML_Error_Error: SSOPARAMS
Backtrace:
0 www/saml2/idp/SSOService.php:22 (N/A)
Caused by: Exception: Unable to find the current binding.
Backtrace:
2 vendor/simplesamlphp/saml2/src/SAML2/Binding.php:104 
(SAML2\Binding::getCurrentBinding)
1 modules/saml/lib/IdP/SAML2.php:315 
(sspmod_saml_IdP_SAML2::receiveAuthnRequest)
0 www/saml2/idp/SSOService.php:19 (N/A)
```

When I am configuring the IdP with simpleSAMLphhp library and register an application, it give me this error on redirection on SP-initiated authentication. Presently IdP has been configured with UserPass auth source.

I also have another setup which is working with same IdP. I configured another SP-application using the simplesamlphp library.

Based on my understanding,
I can see that SAMLRequest is passed in the working example and same is not passed in case of actual Application. Can anyone guide me in fixing the issue ?

Is it the IdP configuration issue ?

Application SP is configured with param  : AssertionConsumerService  (I am not about the param, but this one I can see in the SP-Metadata of the application).